# How can I remove the border line from a FireMonkey TListBox control?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tlistbox, firemonkey-style

I'm learning about FireMonkey styles - my main reference has been [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Customizing_FireMonkey_Applications_with_Styles). Everything I've tried with simple labels and shapes has worked fine but I'm now working with a TListBox and trying to do two things:

1. Set the font of items in a TListBox.
2. Remove its border (it's client aligned in a TCalloutPanel).

I am using the method of creating a StyleBook on the form, right-clicking the control and choosing 'Edit Custom style'. (I'd be equally happy to make runtime changes though).

The only success I've had with the font is to create multiple TListBoxItem's and use their individual text settings. Is there no way of them inherited a parent setting as with VCL? I would really like to add list box items simply as in the VCL with:

```
 ListBox1.Items.Add( 'text' )
```

but I cannot see a run time way of getting at the internal TListBoxItem array that I see is created.

The other problem is that I can see no way of removing the border rectangle. A plain rectangle is easy - it has a stroke - but digging through all the layout options of a TListBox in the StyleBook I just cant see a stroke anywhere.

I'm using XE7. Am I missing something?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: TListBox has a property DefaultItemStyles which is probably what you want but is undocumented so needs some investigation. Removing the outline is more complicated. Check out the Bitmap Style Designer (on the Tools menu) and you'll need a good graphics editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the background will be of `TRectangle` type.

When you choose the ***Edit Custom Style*** option you will be editing a platform default style which is always a Windows style. (That is, if no custom style has been loaded already)

The way they decided to handle platform default styles is by taking snapshots of native controls and merging them in a single image from which they can individually sourcelink to a specific control.
That image is available in the style for you to modify.

1. Setting font of items in a ListBox

   Right click on item and select Edit Custom Style, a new style object is added to your StyleBook. For the listbox item it should be called `listboxitem1style1` altho numbers can vary.(The name comes from the default style for this object which is `listboxitemstyle`). 


   This is the style object that you want to edit in the StyleBook. Once you are done, close the StyleBook and change the `StyleLookup` property of each ListBox item to `listboxitem1style1`. Preferably you should assign the value to the property at runtime.
    `ListBoxItem1.StyleLookup := 'listboxitem1style1';`
2. Removing border from TListBox

   After the custom style is loaded in your StyleBook, using Style designer, navigate to `ListBox1Style1 > background : SourceLink property` and edit the `SourceRect` of the assigned BitmapLink object. Basically you inflate the rectangle by -2 to get rid of the border.

[image]

Comment: That's very helpful thanks Peter. Could you indicate a bit more detail about how to proceed with "you want to be sure that every item has the appropriate styleLookup name assigned to it. You should do this at runtime"? Where do I get the stylelookup name from please?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include more detail on how to accomplish that.

Comment: Works for any control of such nature for that matter :-)

Comment: I've tried with you guidelines for hide the border line for the listbox component, but I dont see the sourcerect in the bitmap link editor. Only I can see sourcelink.